# Mysqld will not start in MacOSX Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: mysql, macos

I tried running the following:

`$ mysqld start`

But I get a log of this:

```
2015-02-19 01:41:48 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-02-19 01:41:48 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 512233130
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Binlog end
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 512233140
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-02-19 01:41:50 37487 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

After I ran into this problem, I uninstalled and reinstalled mysql from cakebrew.

I remember I had mysql server running before, but I don't know why I can't run it now. Any hints? I've tried searching for similar problems but it seemed that the problems are quite specific :S

Comment: "mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is shown right here:

```
mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start'). 
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options 
2015-02-19 01:41:49 37487 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It's telling you that it doesn't understand the word `start` after your mysqld command.  You did use `start` but it doesn't like that.

Use:

```
mysqld --verbose --help
```

For easier reading, you can use:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | more
```

To get a list of options you may want to start it with.

The simplest way to start it would be:

```
mysqld &
```

This will background the process, however, this is probably not the way you want to run it.  I don't use cakebrew, but using homebrew, this is the command I use to start mysql as a one off.

```
mysql.server start
```

Also, you can use lanchctl:

```
To have launchd start mysql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Comment: What does first extra is start means?

Comment: I did used start as my first argument. And there is only 1 argument. Why are there too many arguments.

Comment: There are too many arguments because mysqld is telling you there are too many arguments.  It is telling you "first extra is start"  meaning ... the first extra argument ... is one too many.   By inference, if 1 is too many then 0 is sufficient.  it sounds like you are confusing mysqld with 'services' or some other such Beginner Linux distro daemon control program.